# How to make only single row selected in telerik radgrid detailtables?

Tags: telerik, radgrid

currenetly, I am using the telerik Radgrid control to build a grid. my grid have two levels ( mastertableview and detailtables). In detailtables, there is a gridclientselectcolumn to show a checkbox.

What i want to do is to make only one row selected at each time. That means, when I select a row in a detail table, the other one selected previously need to be deselected.

The allowrowselecting and muliplerowselect are only used to control the mastertableview. Now i need a way to control the detail tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I bumped into a How-to topic from the Telerik AJAX docs that may match your case or become the core of your logic, too - [check it out](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/gridmultiroweditselectiononlyformastertableinhierarchicalgrid.html).

Comment: I have changed to using grouping to implement. Anyway, thanks your suggestion.